# Can I animate the focal length for camera tracking?

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm camera tracking my shot where I zoom in during the shot. When I tried to animate the focal length for the solve, Blender gives me an error that reads: "focal length" property cannot be animated. **Is there a way to animate the focal length or is there an option to solve for a focal length change?**